# ng extract-i18n configuration to ignore duplicate messages

Tags: angular, internationalization

In Angular v10, we are using the in-built i18n feature.
Now when I run the **ng extract-i18n** it returns many duplicate message warnings.

Just a short example:

```
   WARNINGS:
    - Duplicate messages with id "lastName":
      - "Last Name" : src\app\core...\
      - "Last Name" ...
```

However, this is intentional on my part. I'm trying to REUSE certain i18n IDs throughout the application.

i.e. Some HTML snippets from various templates:

```
 <label i18n="Label|Label for Last Name@@lastName">Last Name</label>
 <mat-label i18n="Label|Label for Last Name@@lastName">Last Name</mat-label>
<mat-radio-button value="LastName" i18n="Button|Button for User Preferences@@lastName">
                Last Name</mat-radio-button
              >
<kendo-grid-column
  i18n-title="Title|Title for Orders Grid@@firstName"
  field="Student.FirstName"
  title="First Name"
 ></kendo-grid-column>
```

In other words, text labels like **"Last Name" and "First Name"** are repeated a number of times in our application, so I have one generic i18n tag for each.

The CLI then generates the **id** attrib in the **XLF** output file:

```html
<trans-unit id="lastName" datatype="html">
        <source>Last Name</source>        
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/core/modals/.../info-modal.html</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">33</context>
        </context-group>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/.../student-list.component.html</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">26</context>
        </context-group>
        <context-group purpose="location">
          <context context-type="sourcefile">src/app/.../another-list.component.html</context>
          <context context-type="linenumber">101</context>
        </context-group>        
      </trans-unit>
```

Is there something wrong in this approach? Or is the Angular CLI just trying to be helpful?

I might be able to IGNORE those warnings, but it's not clear how.

I also found some info on github but it's not all too clear. https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/19207

I also found a comment pointing to some config options: https://github.com/angular/angular/blob/79620f5139c80f1b3b38168744ca99a224c7e5cd/packages/localize/src/tools/src/extract/main.ts#L89-L95

Answer (score 3):

Your approach is valid.

The problem (most likely) comes from inconsistent use of white spaces/newlines: observe that in your example one text is `\nLast Name` and another is `Last Name`!

Even though it might make no difference in that case, it is a good practice to keep texts with the same id identical- even with respect to white space.

Comment: This answer should have been accepted. These warnings are easy to fix. And in fact it is important to fix them. If reused i18n IDs do not have *identical* texts (even whitespace, punctuation, and casing), then you do not know which of them that will be extracted, and you may end up with "hard to find" bugs.

Comment: No it should not, this issue is that re-used i18n tokens generated warning messages. It has nothing to do with whitespaces etc. try using json format for i18n and you will se the same warnings